# Detect iFrame src change vs content reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, reload

My basic code looks like this:

```
<iframe id="iFrame1" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<iframe id="iFrame2" style="display: none;"></iframe>

$("#iFrame1").load(function () {
        // display iFrame1, hide iFrame2
        // set timeout to load next page
    });
$("#iFrame2").load(function () {
        // display iFrame2, hide iFrame1
        // set timeout to load next page
    });
```

I have a set list of pages (same domain, no problems with being displayed inside an iFrame) that are to be displayed in the iFrames (only 1 iFrame is visible at a time), looping through on an interval of 30 minutes (the pages are displaying sporting results).

Basically the way this works is that the src of iFrame 1 is set using `$("#iFrame1").attr("src", "<new_url>");`. Once the page has fully loaded, the `load` function triggers and displays iFrame1, hiding iFrame2. A timeout function is then set to load the next page into iFrame2, which will trigger the `load` function and display iFrame2, hiding iFrame1. It has been done this way so that the loading of the page isn't visible to the user, the iFrame is only made visible once the page has finished loading which gives a smooth transition between pages.

This all works fine! The problem is that one of the pages is set to reload itself (`location.reload(true);`) at a specific time of the day, and I have no control over that page. Problem here is that the reload of that page also triggers the `load` function of that iFrame, which causes that iFrame to be incorrectly hidden.

My question is, is there a way to differentiate between the actual src of an iFrame changing, compared to just the content of the iFrame being reloaded (and the src staying the same)? I have had a look at `document.referrer`, but that gives me nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my issue by adding a check to the `load` function of each iFrame to check if the iFrame is already visible or not. Only do the swap if the iFrame isn't currently visible..

```
<iframe id="iFrame1" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<iframe id="iFrame2" style="display: none;"></iframe>

$("#iFrame1").load(function () {
    // If iFrame 1 is hidden, show it
    if($("#iFrame1").css("display") == "none")
    {
            // display iFrame1, hide iFrame2
            // set timeout to load next page
    }
});
$("#iFrame2").load(function () {
    // If iFrame 2 is hidden, show it
    if($("#iFrame2").css("display") == "none")
    {
            // display iFrame2, hide iFrame1
            // set timeout to load next page
    }
});
```